# VBA file copy based on list to specific directory issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am attempting to copy a file with names from an excel list and copy them to a specific directory using VBA. I am using rizvisa1's code from http://ccm.net/forum/affich-689536-generate-excel-workbooks-based-on-excel-list as a base code. I have successfully gotten it to copy the correct file with the names in col A and col B but i also want to copy them to individual folders with a name in col D. So far it will save the files to the fixed path in the code but won't put them in the correct folders (or any for that matter.) I am still pretty new to VBA and am using Excel 2010 if it matters. I have included my code below. 
Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyTemplate()
   Dim lRow, x As Integer
   Dim wbName As String
   Dim fso        As Variant
   Dim dic        As Variant
   Dim colA       As String
   Dim colB       As String
   Dim colSep     As String
   Dim copyFile   As String
   Dim copyTo     As String
   Dim colD     As String

   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'dictionary to ensure that duplicates are not created
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'file scripting object for fiile system manipulation

   colSep = " - " 'separater between values of col A and col B for file name
   dic.Add colSep, vbNullString ' ensuring that we never create a file when both columns are blank in between

   'get last used row in col A
   lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


   x = 1

   colD = Range("D" & x).Value 'Folder to save to

   copyFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\New folder\BackupDocs.xls" 'template file to copy
   copyTo = "C:\Users\User\Documents\New folder\Excel Test\" & colD & "\"  'location where copied files need to be copied

   Do
    x = x + 1

    colA = Range("A" & x).Value 'col a value

    colB = Range("B" & x).Value ' col b value
    colB = Left(Range("B" & x).Value, 20) 'only retain first 20 characters



    wbName = colA & colSep & colB ' create new file name

    If (Not dic.Exists(wbName)) Then 'ensure that we have not created this file name before
      fso.copyFile copyFile, copyTo & wbName & ".xls" 'copy the file
      dic.Add wbName, vbNullString 'add to dictionary that we have created this file
   End If


Loop Until x = lRow

Set dic = Nothing ' clean up
Set fso = Nothing ' clean up

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are setting the variable `copyTo` is outside of the loop so it always just uses the folder value in in D1.  bring `colD=...` and `copyTo...` inside your loop (somewhere after `x=x+` and it should work better.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyTemplate()
   Dim lRow, x As Integer
   Dim wbName As String
   Dim fso        As Variant
   Dim dic        As Variant
   Dim colA       As String
   Dim colB       As String
   Dim colSep     As String
   Dim copyFile   As String
   Dim copyTo     As String
   Dim colD     As String

   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'dictionary to ensure that duplicates are not created
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'file scripting object for fiile system manipulation

   colSep = " - " 'separater between values of col A and col B for file name
   dic.Add colSep, vbNullString ' ensuring that we never create a file when both columns are blank in between

   'get last used row in col A
   lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   copyFile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\New folder\BackupDocs.xls" 'template file to copy

   x = 1

   Do
    x = x + 1

    colA = Range("A" & x).Value 'col a value
    'colB = Range("B" & x).Value ' This line is overwritten by the next line so delete
    colB = Left(Range("B" & x).Value, 20) 'only retain first 20 characters
    colD = Range("D" & x).Value 'Folder to save to

   copyTo = "C:\Users\User\Documents\New folder\Excel Test\" & colD & "\"  'location where copied files need to be copied

    wbName = colA & colSep & colB ' create new file name

    If (Not dic.Exists(wbName)) Then 'ensure that we have not created this file name before
      fso.copyFile copyFile, copyTo & wbName & ".xls" 'copy the file
      dic.Add wbName, vbNullString 'add to dictionary that we have created this file
   End If


Loop Until x = lRow

Set dic = Nothing ' clean up
Set fso = Nothing ' clean up

End Sub
```